# Правильный ли подход к разработке на NodeJS с Express?

Tags: ооп, node.js, mvc, express

Итак, как выглядит проект, начинаем с app.js и заканчиваем темплейтом ejs:

1. Все конфиги, сессии и тд подключается в app.js
2. В app.js подключается файл в котором содержатся rout'ы, этот файл содержит урлы которые передаются далее в другие файлы уже в `app/routers` - тут уже лежат файлы в которых по каждому из урлов опредлены параметры, например если мы передали а `app/routers/login.js` урл `/login` то в нем уже будет подробно:

```js
app.get('/', ... 
    
app.post('/beginRegister', ...
```

3. Далее уже из такого `app/routers/login.js`, мы подключаем контроллер для этих роутов, например `var Login = require(app/controllers/login)`, и уже например внутри `app.post('/beginRegister'...` мы обращаемся к контроллеру Login передав в него `res,req`:

```js
var controller = new Login(res,req);
controller.doRegister();
```

4. В контроллере мы подключаем модель `var Model = require(app/models/login)`. Теперь в контроллере мы имеем `req, res` и создадим экземпляр модели `var model=new Model();`
   И далее уже в методе `doRegister()` контроллера мы обратимся к модели передав в нее данные из формы и коллбэк который выведет результат в браузер:

   model.addUser(req.body,viewResult)

В целом в так я вижу основу, и мне кажется что тут что-то не так, я недавно изучаю noodejs, и вот решил попробовать что-то написать. Оцените правильность такого подхода, если тут есть недостатки или совсем все ужасно, объясните как правильно это делать! Спасибо за потраченное время)

Comment: Что конкретно смущает в имеющемся решении? Описанные детали не указывают на серьезные проблемы.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать советы тех кто имеет на этом хороший опыт

Comment: Наверное вопрос тогда должен звучать как. Порекомендуйте статьи, книги, библиотеки, примеры кода для новичка в NodejS.

Comment: @ФедорРусак может и не совсем так, меня интересует именно MVC подход в node.js, возможно конкретно, как правильно организовать эту структуру в express? как разбить все не только на модели/контроллеры, но и либы, модули, хелперы и т.д. Как правильно наследоваться и что должно быть в базовом контроллере например, и нужен ли он вообще как таковой. Интересны подходы к этому, хочется все правильно организовать что бы потом не пришлось все рубить под корень.